# Missing "Shading [Smooth|Flat]" menu on the left of the screen

Tags: shaders

In a Lynda tutorial, "Shading" should be in the "Mesh Tools" menu, but I can't seem to get to that after selecting several faces of an object.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: While in edit mode you can find it in Shading/UVs tab

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shade in Edit Mode, you need to go to the Shading/UVs tab. From there, you can select to smooth the selected Faces, Edges, or Vertices. Or, if you want to change the whole object to Smooth Shading, you can do it from Object Mode how you usually would. Hope this helps[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgXdy.png)

Comment: @BobW don't forget accept the answer!